# Inserting data into an array for a scatterplot with KendoReact

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a scatterplot from a variable called `data`.
`data` should contain the x and y values for the scatterplot. The method below is what I am attempting to do to insert the x and y values, however the graph is showing up blank.

```
let data = []
for(var i = 0; i < sixth_x.length; ++i){

  data.push({xField: sixth_x[i], yField: sixth_y[i]})

}
```

x is a string, and y is a number.

This is my method to display the graph

```
  <ChartSeriesItem type="scatter" data={data} xField="sixth_x"
    yField="sixth_y"/>
</ChartSeries>
```

Comment: data.push = (...) is it correct syntax? Maybe data.push(...)

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov thanks for noticing that syntax error! Unfortunately I still cannot get points to be displayed

Comment: are you sure sixth_x and sixth_y arrays have values? Try to console `data` array after `for` loop and see if it is filled with correct values expected by ChartSeriesItem component

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov Yes the arrays have values, when I display data after for loop, it is correctly displaying the values. Below is an example of what the data array is holding:
1: Object
xField: "2020-04-27 00:00:00"
yField: 1
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

ChartSeriesItem xField and yField expect property name of source array object. In your case source array object is `{xField: <some string>, yField: <some number>}`.
So you should pass these property names (xField, yField) to your props.
`<ChartSeriesItem type="scatter" data={data} xField="xField" yField="yField"/></ChartSeries>`
which looks strange.

I recommend rename properties to identify what exactly your chart about, ex. price growing per year chart, so you will do something like this
`data.push({price: sixth_x[i], year: sixth_y[i]})`
and `<ChartSeriesItem type="scatter" data={data} xField="price" yField="year"/></ChartSeries>`
I think you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. The Fields were indeed mixed up. It should have been: 


<ChartSeriesItem type="scatter" data={data} xField="xField"
yField="yField"/>